# How to remove set of characters when a string comprise of "\" and Special characters in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

`a = "\Virtual Disks\DG2_ASM04\ACTIVE"`

From the above string I would like to get the part `"DG2_ASM04"` alone. I cannot split or strip as it has the special characters `"\"`, `"\D"` and `"\A"` in it.

Have tried the below and can't get the desired output.

```
a.lstrip("\Virtual Disks\\").rstrip("\ACTIVE")
```

the output I have got is: `'G2_ASM04' instead of "DG2_ASM04"`

Comment: If that's a string literal in your script (and not a string you're reading from some external source) you should make it a raw string.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `slicing` and `escape` backslash(`\`)

```
>>> a.split("\\")[-2]
'DG2_ASM04'
```

In your case `D` is also removing because it is occurring more than one time in given string (thus striping `D` as well). If you tweak your string then you will realize what is happening

```
>>> a = "\Virtual Disks\XG2_ASM04\ACTIVE"
>>> a.lstrip('\\Virtual Disks\\').rstrip("\\ACTIVE")
'XG2_ASM04'
```